# RGB values of CIImage pixel

Tags: swift, arkit, core-image, ciimage, cvpixelbuffer

I want to access the average colour value of a specific area of `CVPixelBuffer` that I get from `ARFrame` in real-time. I managed to crop the image, use filter to calculate average colour and after converting to `CGImage` I get the value from the pixel but unfortunately, it affects the performance of my app (FPS drops below 30fps). I think that the reason for that is using CGContext. Is there a way to access colour without converting `CIImage` to `CGImage`?
This is code that I'm using at the moment:

```swift
func fun() {
  let croppVector = CIVector(cgRect: inputImageRect)

  guard let filter = CIFilter(
    name: "CIAreaAverage",
    parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: image, kCIInputExtentKey: croppVector]
  ),
    let outputImage = filter.outputImage,
    let cgImage = context.createCGImage(
      outputImage,
      from: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 1, height: 1)
    ),
    let dataProvider = cgImage.dataProvider,
    let data = CFDataGetBytePtr(dataProvider.data) else { return nil }

  let color = UIColor(
    red: CGFloat(data[0]) / 255,
    green: CGFloat(data[1]) / 255,
    blue: CGFloat(data[2]) / 255,
    alpha: CGFloat(data[3]) / 255
  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there is not too much you can do here – reduction operations like this are expensive.

A few things you can try:

- Set up your `CIContext` to *not* perform any color management by setting the `.workingColorSpace` and `.outputColorSpace` options to `NSNull()`.
- Render directly into a piece of memory instead of going through a `CGImage`. The context has the method `render(_ image: CIImage, toBitmap data: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, rowBytes: Int, bounds: CGRect, format: CIFormat, colorSpace: CGColorSpace?)` you can use for that. Also pass `nil` as color space here. You should be able to just pass a "pointer" to a `simd_uchar4` var as `data` here. `rowBytes` would be 4 and format would be `.BGRA8` in this case, I think.
- You can also try to scale down your image (which already is a reduction operation) before you do the average calculation. It wouldn't be the same value, but a fair approximation – and it might be faster.

Comment: Thanks Frank for the answer. Unfortunately it didn't help much (maybe improved performance a bit) but I still get cases when frames drop to 18fps. I did captured frame with the Metal Frame Debugger and as a  result I get an Issue: "Encoder: 'mainMetalEntryPoint' has unused texture: 'com.apple.CoreImage' issue" in regards to the cropped image that I calculate the average from. Do you know any other way to get pixel RGB values from CVPixelBuffer? My goal is to compare its values with reference RGB colour.

Comment: You can access the raw data with `CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress`. Concerning the performance: Have you tried _disabling_ "GPU Frame Capture" and "Metal API Validation" in your scheme settings? Those interfere heavily with any performance benchmark.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel what happens if we do not specify workingColorSpace (or outputColorSpace) key when creating a ciContext?

Comment: @DeepakSharma The working space defaults to extended linear sRGB. Same for the output space, I think. But it is rarely used since most of the context's output methods require to explicitly specifying it anyway.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel So conversion to sRGB and back in input and output, is that what we call **color management**?

Comment: @DeepakSharma Right, also called ColorSync by Apple.

Comment: @DeepakSharma Maybe would be better if you ask that in a new question. This comment section is probably not the ideal place to discuss this... 

Comment: Ok will frame a new question and post.

Comment: @FrankSchlegel I tried my best to formulate it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70620628/core-image-workingcolorspace-outputcolorspace). Have a look please.