# Core Image workingColorSpace & outputColorSpace

Tags: ios, metal, core-image

I am rendering video frames using Metal Core Image shaders. One of the requirements I have is to be able to pick a particular color (and user selected nearby range) from the CIImage, keep that color in the output and turn every other else black and white (color splash). But I am confused about the right approach that would work for videos shot in all kinds of color spaces (including 10 bit HDR):

1. First job is to extract the color value from the CIImage at any given pixel location. From my understanding, this can be extracted using the following API:

   ```
   func render(_ image: CIImage, 
     toBitmap data: UnsafeMutableRawPointer, 
     rowBytes: Int, 
     bounds: CGRect, 
     format: CIFormat, 
     colorSpace: CGColorSpace?)
   ```

The API says passing NULL to colorSpace will cause the output to be in ciContext outputColorSpace. It's not clear how to correctly use this API to extract the exact color at given pixel locations, given the possibility of both 8 bit and 10 bit input images?

2. Having extracted the value, the next issue is how to pass the values to Metal Core Image shader? Shaders use normalized color ranges dependent on the *workingcolorSpace* of ciContext. Do I need to create a 1D texture with the color that should be passed to shader or there is a better way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your comment, here is another alternative:

You can read the pixel value *as floats* using the context's *working color space*. By using float values, you ensure that the bit depth of the input doesn't matter and that extended color values are correctly represented.
So for instance, a 100% red in BT.2020 would result in an extended sRGB value of `(1.2483, -0.3880, -0.1434)`.

To read the value, you could use our small helper library [CoreImageExtensions](https://github.com/DigitalMasterpieces/CoreImageExtensions#image-value-access) (or check out the [implementation](https://github.com/DigitalMasterpieces/CoreImageExtensions/blob/7610c402a98dc160e5c247959cef40d2d5af14d2/Sources/CIContext%2BValueAccess.swift#L94) to see how to use `render` to get float values):

```
let pixelColor = context.readFloat32PixelValue(from: image, at: coordinate, colorSpace: context.workingColorSpace)
// you can convert that to CIVector, which can be passed to a kernel
let vectorValue = CIVector(x: pixelColor.r, y: pixelColor.g, ...)
```

In your Metal kernel, you can use a `float4` input parameter for that color.

You can store and use the color value on later rendering calls as long as you are using the same `workingColorSpace` for the context.

Comment: This is the right answer that should work in principle. As you noted, the sRGB values will cross the [0..1] range. Although nothing to do with this question, another problem needs to be solved with color ranges more than 1 or less than 0 -- how to convert to hue and back!

Comment: Yeah, that's a tough one. I recommend you check out the LCh color space. It supports a much wider range of colors than HSL. You have to convert to that manually, though.

Comment: What if I need to manipulate colors in HSL. Can't find any resource on HDR and HSL or HCL!

Comment: You could also set the working color space to the widest space you support, for instance, BT.2020 (`extendedLinearITUR_2020`). Then color values will always be in [0..1]. Then convert to HSL (which is then based on BT.2020 instead of sRGB) and back. That might work and not clamp colors in the process.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can achieve that without worrying about color spaces and even without the intermediate rendering step (which should speed up performance a lot).

You can simply crop your image to a 1x1 px square image that contains the specific color and make the image to extent virtually infinitely in all directions.
You can then pass that image into your next kernel and sample it anywhere to retrieve the color value (in the same color space as before).

```
let pixelCoordinate: CGPoint // the coordinate of the pixel that contains the color

// crop down to a single pixel
let colorPixel = inputImage.cropped(to: CGRect(origin: pixelCoordinate, size: CGSize(width: 1, height: 1))
// make the pixel extent infinite
let colorImage = colorPixel.clampedToExtent()

// simply pass it to your kernel
myKernel.apply(..., arguments: [colorImage, ...])
```

In the Metal kernel code, you can simply access it via `sampler` (or `sample_t` in a color kernel) and sample it like this:

```
// you can sample at any coord since the image contains the single color everywhere
float4 pickedColor = colorImage.sample(colorImage.coord());
```

Comment: I will try this and get back to you if there are any issues.

Comment: Ok so what I see is this method is simply equivalent to storing the pixelCoordinate and the original image and passing both the coordinate and image in the shader (which I am doing currently). The 1x1 pixel image method is better because I can save this 1x1 image in the documents folder to reapply the effect anytime on reloading the app. But in what color space should I save this 1x1 image on disk and how do I do save the it to disk in chosen color space? It needs to match the color space of original image.

Comment: Another approach would be saving the color value & the original colorspace of image to disk and then recreating CIImage from this color value. But I am not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2):

To read the "original" color values from a CIImage, the CIContext used to render the pixels to the bitmap needs to be created with both `workingColorSpace` and `outputColorSpace` set to `NSNull()`. Then there will be no color space conversion and you don't have to worry about color spaces:

```
let context = CIContext(options: [.workingColorSpace: NSNull(), .outputColorSpace: NSNull()])
```

And then, when rendering the pixels to bitmap, specify the highest precision color format `CIFormat.RGBAf` to make sure you are not clipping any values. And use `nil` for `colorSpace` parameter. You will get 4 Float32 values per pixel that can be passed to the shader in CIVector as suggested by the first answer.

But here is another thing you can do, borrowing the cropping and clamping idea from the second Answer.

1. Create an infinite image that contains only the selected color using the approach suggested in that answer.
2. Crop that image to the frame's extent
3. Use `CIColorAbsoluteDifference` where one input is the original frame and another is this uniform color image.
4. The output of that filter will make all pixels that match the selected color exactly back, and none of the other pixels will be black, since this filter calculates the absolute difference between the colors and only pixels of exactly the same color will produce the (0,0,0) output.
5. Pass that image to the shader. If the color sampled from the image has exactly 0 in all its color components (ignore alpha) it means you need to copy the input pixel to the output intact. Otherwise set it to whatever you need it to be set (black or white or whatever).

Comment: With CIColorAbsoluteDifference, is it possible to pass a small range of colors to match rather than exact one color? Because there might be small difference in intensities in neighboring pixels. In any case, I suspect this filter would also execute by color matching to workingColorSpace than "absolute difference" in native color space of image.

Comment: CIColorAbsoluteDifference operates on two images, pixel by pixel, there is no "range of colors "to speak of. The workingSpace is not an issue either since the uniform color image is produced from the original frame image by cropping and clamping. There is no rendering or color space conversion in between, so both of them are in the same working space. Maybe you just simply give it a try and let us know if titworks (and it should).

Comment: When I set both working and output color space to be NSNull(), the output is not correct when rendered in MTKView with extendedDynamicRange enabled on CALayer. The input buffers are also in HDR format requiring no colorspace conversion.